# Storing a number so that it wont be redefined the next iteration of the loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a loop that will count the total number of words inputted as well as the number of words on the given line. Total words is cumulative, however, words on a given line is not. How would I store this number outside of the loop so that it will not be redefined in the next iteration?

My idea was to store them into an `int` array and just display the array afterwards, however this proved more difficult than anticipated.

Here's an Example:

```
Hello World  
cats and dogs
```

OUTPUT:

```
5 words total  
2 3 //2 on line one  and 3 on line two
```

This is what I have thus far:

```
char lines[50];
int numOfLines = 0;
int numOfWords = 0
int i;
int wordsPerLine[50];  //Unused at this point

for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
    fgets(lines,50,stdin);
    if (strcmp(lines, ".\n") == 0){
        break;
    }
    numOfLines++;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(lines); i++){
            if(lines[i] == ' '){
                numOfWords++;
                wordsPerLine[i] = numOfWords; //everything works up until here
            }
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++){
   printf("%d ", wordsPerLine[i]); //trying to print out the array where I'd hope to store them, however I get a bunch of random numbers
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d ", wordsPerLine);` - do you mean `wordsPerLine[i]`?

Comment: Yes, my bad I edited it

Comment: add a semicolon to the end declaration of numOfWords and use a different index in the nested loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are your issues:

- You reuse `i` for the control variable in the inner loop, so it interferes with the outer loop.  Use a separate variable for this (`j`).
- In the outer loop, you start counting at 1, so `wordsPerLine[0]` never gets set.  Start this loop at 0.
- You set `wordsPerLine[i]` to the current value of `numOfWords` which is the total number of words.  Instead, set this value to 0 before the loop and increment on each iteration.
- You need to check for a newline when counting words, otherwise you won't count the last one.

After these changes, your code should look like this:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
        fgets(lines,50,stdin);
        if (strcmp(lines, ".\n") == 0){
                break;
        }
        numOfLines++;
        wordsPerLine[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(lines); j++){
                if(lines[j] == ' ' || lines[j] == '\n'){
                    numOfWords++;
                    wordsPerLine[i]++;
                }
        }
 }
```

EDIT:

Changed how `wordsPerLine` and `numOfWords` are managed so `numOfWords` contains the total words when the outer loop finishes.

Comment: `You never reset numOfWords on each iteration of the inner loop, so you end up with a running total. Set numOfWords = 0 before the inner loop.` isn't that total sum required?

Comment: Come to think of it, that's probably the best way to do it.  You could add up the words per line after as it is now, but that's extra work.  I'll update to improve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as I see it is you're trying to use the same variable `i` twice as counters for two separate loops which leads to *wrong* logic.

Use a separate counter for the outer loop, say, `j` and use *that* variable to index `wordsPerLine` outside the inner loop, at the end of body for outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use different counter in the nested for loop and reset the numofWords

```
char lines[50];
int numOfLines = 0;
int numOfWords = 0;
int i, j;
int wordsPerLine[50];  //Unused at this point

for(i = 1; i <= 1000; i++){
    fgets(lines,50,stdin);
    if (strcmp(lines, ".\n") == 0){
        break;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < strlen(lines); j++){
        if(lines[j] == ' ' || lines[j] == '\n'){
            numOfWords++;
            wordsPerLine[numOfLines]++; //everything works up until here
        }
    }
    numOfLines++;
}
for (i = 0; i < numOfLines; i++){
    printf("words in %d is %d\n", i, wordsPerLine[i]); //trying to print out the array where I'd hope to store them, however I get a bunch of random numbers
}
printf("total words is %d\n", numOfWords);
```